# Class "Zend\Log\Writer\Stream" not found magento2.4.5 And magento2.4.5p1++

Tags: magento2, php-8.1, magento2.4

Magento 2 old versions like magento 2.4.0 are accepted like taht

**I found a solution to fixed custom log t Magento 2.4.3+++++:**

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/mycustom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info("Its working successfully...");
```

I hove it will help for you!

Comment: It's best to actually ask the question & provide an answer afterwards. Then accept that  answer. This helps readers find questions that are similar nature & will help people answering questions to not unnecessarily spend time reading your question just to realize that it is already answered.

Answer (score 5):

This will work with magento 2.4.5

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

in root project.
in composer.json file

verify this:
"require": {
"zendframework/zend-log": "^2.13"
}

if not write this: composer require laminas/laminas-log

https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-log/installation/

Comment: logging in Magento has its own approach that should be followed (and with 2.4.5 monolog is being used); Zend_Log_Writer_Stream should not be called directly.

Comment: logging in Magento has its own approach that should be followed (and with 2.4.5 monolog is being used); Zend_Log_Writer_Stream should not be called directly. –